# Same dates from and to not showing data

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-xi

the following is the sql being executed in my Crystal report.
There seems to be an issue with the same date request. Sometimes it shows data, other times not. We have data every day, we are a mass market company. Is there anything i can do for the sql to do select when from and to dates are the same?

```
SELECT "OEHIS1"."ODORD#", "OEHIS1"."ODORDT", "OEHIS1"."ODNTU$", "OEHIS1"."ODSHP#",   "ICPRT1"."IARC11", "OEHIS1"."ODORDD", "ICPRT1"."IARCC4", "OEHIS1"."ODQTY#", "OEHIS1"."ODRQSD", "MFHHMH"."MHAWGT", "OEHIS1"."ODPRT#", "OEHIS1"."ODPRLC"
FROM ("S10M10"."ASTCCDTA"."EODDETAILS" "OEHIS1" INNER JOIN "S10M10"."ASTDTA"."ICPRT1" "ICPRT1" ON "OEHIS1"."ODPRT#"="ICPRT1"."IAPRT#") INNER JOIN "S10M10"."DLIB"."MFHHMH" "MFHHMH" ON "OEHIS1"."ODORD#"="MFHHMH"."MHORDP"
WHERE "OEHIS1"."ODPRT#" NOT LIKE 'FR%' AND "ICPRT1"."IARCC4"='FIN' AND "OEHIS1"."ODORDD"=20141027 AND NOT ("ICPRT1"."IARC11"='' OR "ICPRT1"."IARC11"='DRS') AND ("OEHIS1"."ODORDT"='CSA' OR "OEHIS1"."ODORDT"='CUS' OR "OEHIS1"."ODORDT"='INT' OR "OEHIS1"."ODORDT"='N4H' OR "OEHIS1"."ODORDT"='NFM' OR "OEHIS1"."ODORDT"='RTR') AND NOT ("OEHIS1"."ODPRLC" LIKE 'CMY%' OR "OEHIS1"."ODPRLC" LIKE 'DSC%' OR "OEHIS1"."ODPRLC" LIKE 'LGC%' OR "OEHIS1"."ODPRLC" LIKE 'X%')
ORDER BY "ICPRT1"."IARC11"
```

Comment: I have very little CR experience, but with SQL you usually want to select between the day you want and the day after if you want results for today.  That's because today, for example, is `10/27/2014`, with no time. This defaults to midnight.  If the date is the same on both sides, you'll only get results that happened at exactly midnight.  Your query should be between `10/27/2014` and `10/28/2014` (midnight this morning to midnight tomorrow).

Answer (score 0):

Migrated my comment to an answer, since that seemed to work for you.

I have very little CR experience, but with SQL you usually want to select between the day you want and the day after if you want results for today. That's because today, for example, is `10/27/2014`, with no time. This defaults to midnight. If the date is the same on both sides, you'll only get results that happened at exactly midnight. Your query should be between `10/27/2014` and `10/28/2014` (midnight this morning to midnight tomorrow).